# Calling Java Methods from Shell Scripts

Tags: java, shell

How to execute a Java method from inside shell scripts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can only call the `main` method. Design your `main` method such that it calls the method you want.

When I say *call* `main` method, you don't explicitly invoke it. It's the only entry point to a java program when you invoke it.

If your class looks like:

```
package com.foo;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

You can use the following command line to invoke the `main` from within the directory where you can find `com/foo/Test.class` (If you're in the `classes` directory in the structure shown far below):

```
java com.foo.Test
```

If you want to do so from a different (See the directory structure far below) directory, then you'll have to set classpath.

```
java -cp /path/to/classes com.foo.Test
```

Assume the below directory structure for clarity.

```
-path
    -to
        -classes
            -com
                -foo
                    >Test.class
```

Comment: Oh, and by the way do any of you guys know of a neat online service where I can quickly rig up directory structures (text format) like the above?

Answer (score 3):

You can't execute an arbitrary method directly from a shell script, you'll need to have that method exposed externally in some way.

The simplest way of course is to write a `main` method that directly invokes the code you want to test.

Alternatively, you could make use of a Java application that takes parameters to act as a sort of launcher.  In its crudest form you can imagine an app that takes a classname and method name as arguments, then instantiates the class and invokes the method via reflection.  In a similar vein, but a bit more elegant, we use an app that invokes operations exposed via JMX in order to fire certain methods on a server when required.

Ultimately though, `bash` (or equivalent) doesn't understand JVM bytecode.  You **will** need to launch a Java process to run the method, which will involve executing *some* `main` method that in turn invokes what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell script and call your java program like this:

```
`#!/bin/bash 
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_02 
CLASSPATH=/home/freddy/myapp/lib/whatever.jar: . 
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH MyJavaClass 
exit 0`
```

Answer (score -1):

Try **bashj** (a bash mutant with java support) https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashj/. It is intended to cover your need (and much more):

for instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj
echo Math.cos(0.5)
echo Math.hypot(3.0,4.0)
echo System.getProperty("java.runtime.version")
```

You can also put your own methods in a jar loaded by bashj, or include some java source code within the bashj script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj
#@java
public static int factorial(int n) 
{if (n<=0) return(0);
 if (n==1) return(1);
 return(n*factorial(n-1));}
#@bash
echo j.factorial(10)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Dear Mark, I suggested a full path for a good solution to the raised question. The code would fill a lot of space, and I don't have it. So I certainly view it as a a valid answer - more than others who stated that there is no answer.