# How to call JAVA class methods using shell script?

Tags: java, java-6

I have been working on a solution.  Need to call a method written in JAVA program using a shell script command. Is there a way to call non `main` methods.

I'm using a .sh file's to (start & stop) the program.  By any way can i write a script to call the non "Main" method.

Comment: You can not call non main method directly, instead you can pass argument to main method and based on the input(use if-else) call method to start or stop.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem -- what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Could you please provide an example which method you want to call?

Comment: Check out below link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411972/calling-java-methods-from-shell-scripts][1]

Answer (score 2):

Only `main` method can be called from shell script.

Example is:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String []arg)
    {
        String input = arg[0];
        if ("start".equals(input))
            //call start method
        else if ("stop".equals(input))
            //call stop method
        else
            //define default behaviour
    }
}
```

**Shell**

```
java -cp /path/class Test start
```

This will call `main` method of the Test class and pass `start` as argument.

And `-cp` represents path to java class file.
Assumption is that java's path is already set in environment.

**EDIT** : You can not call non main method directly, instead you can pass argument to main method and based on the input(use if-else) call method to start or stop

Comment: Is there a way to call non main method ?

Comment: Not directly, but a workaround will be to call that method from maiin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method from shell it is definitely an entry point for your application. Simply write a class with main method which calls the desired method, build your jar and execute it as a regular java application.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following MyFirstJavaProgram.java

```
public class MyFirstJavaProgram {

   /* This is my first java program.
    * This will print 'Hello World' as the output
    */

   public static void main(String []args) {
      System.out.println("Hello World"); // prints Hello World
   }
}
```

And a correctly installed Java on your computer, you can do the following

```
C:\> javac MyFirstJavaProgram.java
C:\> java MyFirstJavaProgram 
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- a simple method would be: you "fix" somehow the methods to invoke. Like: your main class parses a numerical argument, that you then use to "lookup" the method to invoke from within a table for example
- you can use *reflection* to implement a single `main()` method that reads the names of methods (and even the name of the enclosing class) from the command line, to then execute "by name"
- you can avoid reflection, and basically have **one** `main()` method *per* "other method" you want to invoke (of course that means that you end up with plenty of classes - each one having one `main()` inside
- you could look into [jython](http://www.jython.org/index.html): this tool allows you to run a python interpreter **inside** a specific JVM instance.

The jython solution might be more work - but in case you are trying to solve a "real world" problem, this should be your first choice.

Comment: Given the level of programming skill demonstrated by the question, these suggestions are unrealistic.

Comment: That edit is more balanced so I've removed the down vote.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comeback. Any hints what is missing to fully reverse your decision and getting you in direction of an upvote? ;-)

Comment: I think @Batty answer's is spot on for this user, so avoiding duplicating that,  perhaps expand your alternatives so they are offer more guidance for the slightly less inexperienced.  E.g. with some short example test/run harnesses.  An simple example based your class factory example could be pretty straight forward and flexible next step and enough.